# Segmentation fault using IDXGIAdapter

Tags: directx-9, dxgi

I am reading through the [relevant Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiadapter-getdesc) and found this example of how to create `IDGI` data struct then use it to read memory size but I get `Segmentation fault`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <D3D9Types.h>

LPDIRECT3D9       g_pDirect3D = NULL;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 g_pDirect3D_Device = NULL;


int main(void)
{
    UINT x = 0; // Ordinal number that denotes the display adapter. 
    DWORD xWord = 0 ; 
    D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9 pIdentifier ;
    g_pDirect3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    HRESULT hResult = g_pDirect3D->GetAdapterIdentifier(x, xWord, &pIdentifier);
    IDXGIDevice * pDXGIDevice;
    HRESULT hr  = g_pDirect3D->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)&pDXGIDevice);
    IDXGIAdapter * pDXGIAdapter;
    
    pDXGIDevice->GetAdapter(&pDXGIAdapter); // segfault at this line

    return 0;
}
```

every thing works perfectly but when I uncomment the line before `return 0;` I get the error

```
Microsoft Basic Render Driver
Segmentation fault
```

why do I get that error

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a `IDXGIDevice` reference from a `IDirect3D9` reference using QueryInterface.

The return `HRESULT` from the QueryInterface call is probably `0x80004002` (`E_NOINTERFACE`), so `pDXGIDevice` is null and the following calls cause a crash. You should always check HRESULT values.

Otherwise, for new developments, you should forget about DirectX9 and use DirectX11 or DirectX12 (and this will enable [DXGI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi)).